# GraphQL - Triggering a selective subscription from a BackgroundService

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I am facing an architectural issue with the following setup:

A frontend (React), an ASP.NET Core Backend that consumes messages from a Kafka server. The frontend receives a token from an Auth0 instance that also returns a tenant id inside that token. THe ASP.NET Core middleware, when a resource is requested via the GraphQL (using HotChocolate) query, retrieves that token and gets the tenant id. With that, if data is queried, only data for that specific tenant is returned without the client knowing anything about this.

Now this works fine - the problem arises when a message from Kafka arrives. Currently it is a IHostedService, then when an event comes in, can use a `ITopicEventSender` to inform clients about that message. The message contains also the tenantid.

Only clients that share the same tenant id as the message should be informed. My idea was to let the client pass in the tenant-id as a parameter for the subscription, but how to make this tamper-proof so that a client doesn't get messages from a different tenant.

Is there a better way of achieving that without the chance of the client to tamper with the data?

Here the flow as a small diagram:

[image: flow]

Comment: TBH do not follow what is the problem here. Backend receives the message, finds frontend to inform based on the tenant in the message and that's it. (I assume you are using something like SignalR to communicate to the frontend)

Comment: I use GraphQL with subscriptions. The problem is that only a certain amount of people (with a given tenant id) should be informed.

I could have the tenant id as parameter for the subscription, but the frontend should have no way of tempering (aka using another tenant) for the subscription

Comment: Have not worked with GraphQL subscriptions but as far as I understand they should usually work over websockets and  you can send auth info there. Just use the send auth info to extract the tenant.

Comment: I could not find much info about subscription authorization in HotChocolate but as workaround you can make the token as the parameter of the subscription. See also [one](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#5-authenticate-over-websocket-optional), [two](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/3119), [three](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/1319)